# Manage rollback on transaction in my managed bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, rollback

I am using JPA/hibernate, Spring and JSF.
so my application is organized as following:
I have my entities,
My Dao Interface and implementation **for each entity** where I define basic methods: `findById`, `add`, `update`, `remove` ...
and then I have my service layer which just use DAO interfaces and where ther is basically the same methods as in my DAO.
My problem is that in my backing bean, I have a method `Add_hospital()`, which add a hospital and also services in that hospital, so my method looks like

```
add_hospital(){ 
add-hospital(); 
add-services();
add-Hospital-schedule();
}
```

so this method is a transaction and I want that if some issue happen, the transaction rollback, but I know that the rollback need to be managed in my DAO, will I need to define my method `Add_hospital()` in my managed bean, and it's in this stage where I have this combination of inserts.
Please how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions should be managed on the service layer, not data access.
Example from [spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html):

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
        // do something
    }

    // these settings have precedence for this method
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jonasnas for your answer. So that means that my method add_hospital() which contain all those other methods needs to be defined in my service layer, I taught that in service layer we need to define only basic methods and each service class need to manage only one entity.

Comment: You put all DB queries to DAO class. Usually you have create/remobe/update/update/delete hospital (can be more). You don't worry about transactions at this layer. Then in service layer if you need only  createHospital() then you create transactional method and call that single method dao.createHospital inside it. But if you need to create a method which does multiple calls from dao then you create transactional method and put multiple dao calls inside it.

Comment: The idea of the service layer is that your code uses it without knowing anything about lower lavel. For example in you code you call (transactional) hospitalService.scheduleAppointment(hospital, person) but you don't care if it communicates with database or stores it in memory or calls webservices. Also if you put transactions on DAO level its might be difficult to reuse in other services, which need to do extra db calls in the same transaction

Comment: Thank you sooo much @jonasnas it becomes much clearer for me now :)